# What is .join() is doing in this list comprehension?

Tags: python, methods, list-comprehension

The code is as follows:

```
board = [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' ]
for row in [board[i*3:(i+1) * 3] for i in range(3)]:
     print('| ' + ' | '.join(row) +' |')
```

The code produces the following output:
[image: output1]

The objective here is to print the board for tic tac toe. I pulled this snippet from a tutorial I was watching.

My question is, what exactly is .join(row) doing here?

To provide further context, I know that the .join() method is used to append the items in an iterable to a string. So as I understand it, shouldn't it be adding a three spaces to item, ' | ' such that it looks like: ' |    '? This does not happen though. Instead, a single extra space is distributed across the three '|'s.

Furthermore, when I play around this code, some strange things happen that I can't explain. They are as follows:

1. when you use .join(row) it produces another column of '|'. If you entirely get rid of it, you only have three columns of '|' instead of four.
2. If you change the range from range(3) to range(4), it prints the following:

[image: | | | | | | | | | | | | | |]

However, if instead of .join() you simply write in another instance of ' | ' to be printed, it will simply print the original output with an added row at the bottom.

3. If you change board[i*3:...] to board[i*2:...], it prints the following:

[image: | | | | | | | | | | | | | | |]

Again, if you do not use the .join(row) method, such strange behavior doesn't occur. It just prints the exact same output as when it was three.

4. Lastly, if you change the big end of the board slice from board[board[i*3:(i+1) * 3] to board[i*3:(i+1) * 2], it prints the following:

[image: | | | | | | |]

Is there anyone who can make sense of what .join(row) is doing here and how it is doing it?

Obviously printing a board for tic tac toe is simple enough, but I've been working on understanding this list comprehension for two days now and have still not cracked what is going on here.

Also, if it's any help , in the tutorial she explained this by saying, ".join is just saying to join them in a string where the separator is this vertical line"

Comment: Well, the `.join()` method joins the elements from the iterable interspersed with the string object. So `'a'.join('zxyw')` becomes: `zaxayaw`.

Comment: You can run `' | '.join([1,2,3])` at an interactive prompt to see for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 spaces between the bars.
Now let's break the code:

```
[board[i*3:(i+1) * 3] for i in range(3)] 
will give
[[' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ']]
```

when we loop over above list, each row will be

```
[' ', ' ', ' ']
```

so **' | '.join(row)** is basically joining the 3 spaces witj ' | '

```
print('| ' + ' | '.join(row) +' |')
```

Above print statement is equivalent to

```
print('| ' + '  |   |  ' + ' |')
```

For clarity I am using **#** instead of space( )

```
print('|#' + '##|###|##' + '#|')
```

Comment: Thank you for your super clear reply. Very helpful. I have two follow up questions though if you have the time. 1) is the .join() adding three spaces after just the '|' that it is attached to? And 2) how did you end up, in your last code line, with two spaces before the 2nd '|', and after the third '|' when, in what is originally written (the strings in the print statement), only one space is given?

Comment: @Bigglesworth95 I am sorry for the late reply. If you still have doubts or any individual with similar doubts, it might be helpful. so suppose you have a list  _lst = ['a', 'a', 'a']_. if you perform _'a|a'.join(lst)_, the result will be **aa|aaa|aa**. here **row** is basically a list of 3 spaces.

Answer (score 1):

This code

```py
[board[i*3:(i+1) * 3] for i in range(3)]
```

effectivelly creates a new list like `board`, but as a 3x3 2d list:

```py
[
  [' ', ' ', ' '],
  [' ', ' ', ' '],
  [' ', ' ', ' '],
]
```

Now when we iterate over it in the loop, we will be getting each row from the 2d list above.
When we join one of the rows, we will effectively insert `' | '` in between each of the elements of the `row`.

The `.join` is actually not in any list comprehension, it's in body of a `for` loop iterationg over a list-comprehended list.

Comment: Hi Krystof. Thanks for replying. I have another question tho if you have the time. Basically, my question is then, what is the utility of using .join() here instead of just writing in another ' | '?  Also, I am not sure I understand what you are saying because, if I set it to just print '|'.join(row), shouldn't it print '|' three times? (Once for each row)

Comment: The the strings in `row` contains spaces, so `'|'.join(row)` should print `' | | '` (spaces in `row` separated by the tube)